# Magento 2 | Remove telephone

Tags: magento2

how can I remove the telephone number from everywhere so that it doesn't appear by filling an address and from everything else.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From 2.2 onwards, you can remove telephone from `Store > Configuration > CUSTOMERS > Customer Configuration -> Name and Address options`